# Finding Elements not attached to Document

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

*in short*

Elements created by `createElement` and/or `createElementNS` aren't attached the the main document object at the time of creation, so I can't use `document.getElementById` to find them until they are attached to the main DOM tree.

Is there an efficient way to 'get' nodes that are *off* the main DOM tree?

*to elaborate:*

I'm writing code to generate SVG diagrams dynamically and I can't embed them into the main document until a later point in time. The diagrams are reasonably complicated and I have various functions that each design a portion of the diagram. Each of these functions needs to be able to *find* the right element of the main SVG object in order to put the elements in the right order. It would be perfect if I could call `getElementById` from the main SVG node, but I can't since it's not a `document`.

So I'm stuck with parsing the arrays returned by `getElementsByTagName` and looking for a target id. Alternatively, I can create an invisible `div` in the main document and attach it to that, but I want my code to be reusable and not bound to a particular HTML page.

Can I have more than one `document` object? Say a temporary one that's not displayed where I can build my own DOM (like a video buffer)

Comment: You can use `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Why would you not just have a storage object or even secondary documentFragment to keep those objects until you're ready to add them to the real DOM? Using a documentFragment, you can even use query selectors to find them.

Comment: `documentFragment` is *exactly* what I'm looking for!